# How to sync data from google sheets to excel via Connord Phillips' method

Tags: excel, forms, google-sheets

I've found many (paying) apps, but no real free solutions. Several interesting programs such as DataEverywhere, Zapier etc., but either they aren't free or they don't really do what I want.

I tried by making a google form, linked to a Google spreadsheet, and then use [the method here stated by Connor Phillips'](http://www.connordphillips.com/2016/01/15/syncing-google-sheets-data-to-excel/). Creating the Google form and link it to a google spreadsheet worked, no problem, same with the publishing to the web.

When searching for the file, I can't select/enable `.txt` files to be searched for. When typing in the name, the file is found. When opening this file, I get a quite old-fashioned prompt, saying the file can't be read. I have two blank rows in the `.txt file` as indicated by Connor Phillips.

Does anyone know the problem could be? I use Office 2013 on Windows 8.

Any other solutions/methods to achieve syncing data from a Google spreadsheet to an Excel sheet, of getting data from an online form to an excel sheet are welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the solution was easier even than Connord Phillips' method, as explained [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/7uJXwnJgPhc):

Step 1: In your Google Docs spreadsheet, click file, then Publish to the Web.
Step 2: Open Excel 2010 (I cannot promise that this works in earlier versions, but you can try or Google it)
Step 3: Click the "DATA" Tab on the top
Step 4: There is a "Get External Data" section, click "from web"
Step 5: Return to your spreadsheet in Google Docs, in the Publish to the Web box, start publishing, then look lower in the box, get a website link to your spreadsheet, copy it.
Step 6: Return to Excel and paste the website into the address bar of the dialog box that opened when you clicked get data from the web
Step 7: Click the check box that appears in the upper left of your website (in the Excel Dialog Box)
Step 8: Import and Enjoy!!